# Validating private helper method's parameters

Tags: java, methods, assert

I'm reading J. Bloch's Effective Java and now I'm at the section about validating method parameters. He said the following:

> For an unexported method, you as the package author control the
>   circumstances under which the method is called, so you can and
>   should ensure that only valid parameter values are ever passed  in.
>   **Therefore, nonpublic methods should generally check their parameters**
>   **using *assertions***.

This is the example from the book:

```
// Private helper function for a recursive sort
private  static void sort(long a[], int offset, int length) {
    assert a != null;
    assert offset >= 0 && offset <= a.length;
    assert length >= 0 && length <= a.length - offset;
    // Do the computation
}
```

I don't see how the emphasized sentence implies from ensuring that the parameter values is valid. Moreover, I consulted with [JLS 14.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10) and found this:

> An assertion is either enabled or disabled. [...] **If the assertion
>   is disabled, execution of the assertion has no effect whatsoever**.

I have never used the assert statement in code so, to me it seems error-prone, because if it happens that assertion is disabled it may cause hardly-detected bugs to appear. And he also said this:

Couldn't you clarify the point of what he says?

I mean, why don't we use `assert` for public methods as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the main usage of assertion should be for detecting bugs in your program that you'll be able to fix them.

It's important thing to note that they can be *enabled* and *disabled*. You *don't* want `public` methods to ignore assertions if you're using them to validate arguments - argument checks for `public` methods should be **always** done (if needed, of course).

Another thing to note, assertions are not informative, the message that can be retrieved due to an assertion error is:

```
AssertionFailedException ...
```

which is not usefull like throwing informative exception indicating what was the error and why, which is very helpful for the caller.

Comment: Well, it's seems very strange to me, that sometimes we need to check that the paramter of a private method is valid by turning the assertions on, but sometimes we don't. Can't imagine any case in practice. If we turn off the asertions, the clients of the private method are free to pass any garbage data as paramters. Even if the client of those method are the only another method from the class or nested/inner classes.

Comment: But until then you have (hopefully) discovered the bugs and fixed them. I would never keep assertions in production code, but that's only me - others might disagree.

Comment: __I would never keep assertions in production code__ This I think very useful note, thank you. So it's good to use assertion in private methods, because we've __already done all validations in a public one__ calling it and It will make detecting validation bugs before deploying more simply. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. I use them to make sure that **I** call them correctly, once I'm sure I simply disable the checks.